# What are the possible reasons for a Filter in the common navigator not to work?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I did everything like @prashanth said in [Filtering contents in Eclipse Common Navigator Framework view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47507660/filtering-contents-in-eclipse-common-navigator-framework-view) but my filter doesn't seem to hide anything, I can see all files. 
I also tried to follow everystep of this tutorial, and read the doc : https://help.eclipse.org/photon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fcnf.htm 
I went to the filter menu and made sure the other filter were working and mine was activated. I tried to refresh the tree..
I have absolutely no clue where to look. Do you have an idea that I can explore ? or could you have a look at my code and tell me if you see something wrong ?

my plugin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?><plugin>
  <extension
        point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
     <category
           description="A plugin for managing the configuration files of the  Software Product Line framework"
           id="SPL.commands.category"
           name="SPL - Software Product Line">
     </category>
     <command
           categoryId="SPL.commands.category"
           defaultHandler="spl.handlers.ListConfigHandler"
           id="SPL.commandListConfig"
           name="lister les configurations">
     </command>
     <command
           categoryId="SPL.commands.category"
           id="SPL.commandCreateConfig"
           name="Créer une configuration">
     </command>
     <command
           id="SPL.JavaFileCommand"
           name="Java File Command">
     </command>
  </extension>
  <extension
        point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
     <handler
           class="spl.handlers.JavaFileHandler"
           commandId="SPL.JavaFileHandler">
     </handler>
     <handler
           class="spl.handlers.ListConfigHandler"
           commandId="SPL.ListConfigHandler">
     </handler>
     <handler
           class="spl.handlers.CreateConfigHandler"
           commandId="SPL.commandCreateConfig">
     </handler>
  </extension>
  <extension
        point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
     <key
           commandId="SPL.commands.splCommand"
           schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
           contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window"
           sequence="M1+6">
     </key>
  </extension>
  <extension
        point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
     <menuContribution
           locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?after=help">
        <menu
              id="SPL.menus.sampleMenu"
              label="SPL Menu"
              mnemonic="L">
           <menu
                 label="insérer @Variability">
              <command
                    commandId="SPL.commandListConfig"
                    label="lister les configurations"
                    style="push">
              </command>
              <command
                    commandId="SPL.commandCreateConfig"
                    label="Créer une configuration"
                    style="push">
              </command>
           </menu>
           <menu
                 label="insérer @Bridge"
                 mnemonic="b">
           </menu>
        </menu>
     </menuContribution>
     <menuContribution
           locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any">
                  <menu
              id="SPL.menus.sampleMenu"
              label="SPL Menu"
              mnemonic="L">
                  <menu
                 label="insérer @Variability">
              <command
                    commandId="SPL.commandListConfig"
                    label="lister les configurations"
                    style="push">
              </command>
              <command
                    commandId="SPL.commandCreateConfig"
                    label="Créer une configuration"
                    style="push">
              </command>
           </menu>
           <menu
                 label="insérer @Bridge"
                 mnemonic="b">
           </menu>
           </menu>
     </menuContribution>
  </extension>
  <extension
        id="SPLPerspective"
        name="SPL Perspective"
        point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
     <perspectiveExtension
           targetID="SPL.perspective4">
     </perspectiveExtension>
  </extension>
  <extension
        point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
     <category
           id="SPL"
           name="SPL">
     </category>
     <view
           category="SPL"
           class="spl.views.VariabilityExplorer"
           id="SPL.VariabilityExplorer"
           name="Point of Variability Explorer"
           restorable="true">
     </view>
     <view
           category="SPL"
           class="spl.views.configurationFileExplorer"
           id="spl-development-plugins.configurationFileExplorer"
           name="Configuration File Explorer"

           restorable="true">
     </view>
     <view
           category="SPL"
           class="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigator"
           id="spl-development-plugins.VariabilityNavigator"
           name="VariabilityNavigator"
           restorable="true">
     </view>
  </extension>
  <extension
        point="org.eclipse.help.contexts">
     <contexts
           file="contexts.xml">
     </contexts>
  </extension>
  <extension
        point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectives">
     <perspective
           class="spl.perspectives.PerspectiveFactory4"
           id="SPL.perspective4"
           name="SPL">
     </perspective>
  </extension>
  <extension
        point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
     <editor
           class="spl.editors.PropertiesEditor"
           default="true"
           extensions=".properties"
           id="spl-development-plugins.splEditorProperties"
           name="SPL Properties Editor">
     </editor>
  </extension>
  <extension
        point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.viewer">
     <viewerContentBinding
           viewerId="spl-development-plugins.VariabilityNavigator">
        <includes>
           <contentExtension
                 pattern="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resourceContent">
           </contentExtension>
           <contentExtension
                 pattern="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.*">
           </contentExtension>
           <contentExtension
                 pattern="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.filters.*">
           </contentExtension>
           <contentExtension
                 pattern="spl-development-plugins.VariabilityContent">
           </contentExtension>
        </includes>
     </viewerContentBinding>
     <viewerActionBinding
           viewerId="spl-development-plugins.VariabilityNavigator">
        <includes>
           <actionExtension
                 pattern="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.*">
           </actionExtension>
        </includes>
     </viewerActionBinding>
  </extension>
  <extension
        point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent">
     <navigatorContent
           id="spl-development-plugins.VariabilityContent"
           name="Variability File Contents"
           contentProvider="VariabilityContentProvider"
           labelProvider="VariabilityLabelProvider"
           activeByDefault="true"
           icon="icons/sample.png"
           priority="normal">
        <triggerPoints>
           <or>
              <and>
                 <instanceof
                       value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
                 </instanceof>
                 <test
                       forcePluginActivation="true"
                       property="org.eclipse.core.resources.extension"
                       value="java">
                 </test>
              </and>
              <instanceof
                    value="spl.navigator.VariabilitiesTreeData">
              </instanceof>
           </or>
        </triggerPoints>
        <possibleChildren>
           <or>
              <instanceof
                    value="spl.navigator.VariabilitiesTreeData">
              </instanceof>
           </or>
        </possibleChildren>
     </navigatorContent>
     <commonFilter
           activeByDefault="true"
           class="spl.filter.VariabilityFilter"
           description="hide all files that are not java and whom doesn&apos;t includes @Variability"
           id="spl-development-plugins.commonFilterVariability"
           name="Variability files">
     </commonFilter>
  </extension>
```

My filter : I know the code doesn't match with the class name, it is for testing purposes only. I got the code from here https://github.com/maxeler/eclipse/blob/master/eclipse.jdt.ui/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/ui/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/filters/JavaFileFilter.java which BTW offer other filters whom I tried with the same result :

```
public class VariabilityFilter extends ViewerFilter {

    public VariabilityFilter() {
    }

    /* 
     * Filters out all compilation units and class files elements.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean select(Viewer viewer, Object parent, Object element) {
        if (element instanceof ITypeRoot)
            return false;

        if (element instanceof IPackageFragment)
            try {
                return ((IPackageFragment)element).getNonJavaResources().length > 0;
            } catch (JavaModelException ex) {
                return true;
            }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Note: VariabilityNavigator is an empty class extending CommonNavigator and VariabilitiesTreeData is an empty class.

Comment: Is the `select` method of the filter being called? What is the type of the `element` that is passed to the filter?

Comment: Thanks a lot Greg, I've been on that issue for long`select` : I don't personnaly but then there is nothing in any tutorial about that. I guess it's called automatically by the PDE. `element`would be a file I guess. Does that help ?I was wondering if I should code the VariabilityNavigator, VariabilityContentProvider, VariabilityLabelProvider and VariabilitiesTreeData.......

Comment: I am asking you to do some debugging and find out if the select is actually called, and if it is called to determine what the actual types of the `element` are.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. You are right, it's never called. I did a simple print which is never printed. so I wouldn't know what element is

Comment: Hi Greg, thank u for this new lead but I'm still stuck. I read many things & this :  https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-TreeViewer/TreeViewerArticle.htm .From what I understood, `select` from the Filter should be called from `createPartControl(Composite aParent)` of the viewer but I had no luck with that. And I can't get my head around why it's not in the ContentProvider. It should be more efficient to transform only the domain object that are filtered, no ? Also, it's strange that there is nothing about it in both tutorials. Is it possible to link this `select` via PDE ? thanks

Comment: That TreeViewer article is about just using the JFace `TreeViewer` and related clases directly. Your question is about using these classes via the Common Navigator Framework (CNF) APIs which uses lots of extension points to define an extensible way of contributing things to a view. I am not an expert on CNF

Comment: My issue dispeared but  I don't know why.. maybe it was a typo... or maybe it was a conflict with PDE. the constructor and Select() method is now called. thanks @greg-449